# Where is the stdin if `input()` not assigned to a variable

Tags: python

In shell script,
If no variables are listed after the `read` command,
a default variable: REPLY will be assigned all the input

```
    $ read
    test
    $ echo $REPLY
    test
```

Nevertheless, in python

```
    In [1]: input(": ")
    : test
    Out[1]: 'test'
    In [2]: #it's gone
```

Where could I find the 'test'?

Comment: @Farhan.K wrong, you can use `_` for this

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre My bad. Didn't know `_` automatically gets assigned

Comment: no problem! now you know at least. I learned it reading stackoverflow site a few months ago.

Comment: `Out[1]` will also give you the same thing in IPython shell.